# Group of tabulars under one table reference

Tags: tables, subfloats

I'm trying to reproduce a structure like this:

[image]

But all I could come up with was the following code:

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Global caption}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \caption*{$G$}
        \centering
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|lll}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    \textbf{Vertex} & \textbf{Label}\\ \cline{1-2}
                    b               & 1             \\
                    c               & 1             \\
                    d               & 1             \\ \cline{1-2}
                \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption*{$F$}
                \begin{tabular}{|c|c|lll}
                    \cline{1-2}
                    \textbf{Vertex} & \textbf{Label}\\ \cline{1-2}
                    b               & 1             \\
                    c               & 1             \\
                    d               & 1             \\ \cline{1-2}
                \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption*{Global caption}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \caption*{$G$}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|lll}
            \cline{1-2}
            \textbf{Vertex} & \textbf{Label}\\ \cline{1-2}
            b               & 1             \\
            c               & 1             \\
            d               & 1             \\ \cline{1-2}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption*{$F$}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|lll}
            \cline{1-2}
            \textbf{Vertex} & \textbf{Label}\\ \cline{1-2}
            b               & 1             \\
            c               & 1             \\
            d               & 1             \\ \cline{1-2}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption*{Global caption}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \caption*{$G$}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|lll}
            \cline{1-2}
            \textbf{Vertex} & \textbf{Label}\\ \cline{1-2}
            b               & 1             \\
            c               & 1             \\
            d               & 1             \\ \cline{1-2}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption*{$F$}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|lll}
            \cline{1-2}
            \textbf{Vertex} & \textbf{Label}\\ \cline{1-2}
            b               & 1             \\
            c               & 1             \\
            d               & 1             \\ \cline{1-2}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage} 
\end{table}
```

which somewhat resembles the structure, but keeps my tables way too much separated from each other. Can anyone suggest me a better way to obtain the desired results?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the `lll` columns in our tables preambles supposed to do, since they're empty?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the subfig or the subcaption packege.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also possible to build these tabulars using [cals](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals) and one `calstable`. By defining shortcuts for removing cell border, it is convinient to remove the necessary borders around the cells. Of cause, sub-labels are ordinary text, so it is not possible to refer to `subtable 1(c)`. If you prefer more narrow table, just increase the the divisor when calculating the column width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals, caption}

\let\nc=\nullcell                        % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{calstable}[c] % Centre the tabular

% Defining columns relative to the margin 
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}  % Increase 5 to 6 or 7 to make the tabular more narrow 
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/5\relax}
            }

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.4pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.4pt}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.4pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.4pt}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Botton border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}


% R1H1
\brow
    \lb\tb\rb\alignC\nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{$G$}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{$H$}\lb\tb\rb
\erow
% R2B1
\brow
    \cell{Vertex}
    \cell{Label}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{Vertex}
    \cell{Label}
\erow
% R3B2
\brow
    \cell{b}
    \cell{1}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{c}
    \cell{1}
\erow
% R4B3
\brow
    \cell{c}
    \cell{1}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{a}
    \cell{1}
\erow
% R5B4
\brow
    \cell{d}
    \cell{1}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{d}
    \cell{1}
\erow
% R6B5
\brow
    \lb\rb\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{(a)}\lb\rb
\erow
% R7B6
\brow
    \lb\tb\rb\alignC\nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{$G$}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{$H$}\lb\tb\rb
\erow
% R8B7
\brow
    \cell{Vertex}
    \cell{Label}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{Vertex}
    \cell{Label}
\erow
% R9B8
\brow
    \cell{c}
    \cell{11}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{a}
    \cell{11}
\erow
% R10B9
\brow
    \cell{d}
    \cell{10}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{d}
    \cell{11}
\erow
% R11B10
\brow
    \rb\lb\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{(b)}\rb\lb
\erow
% R12B11
\brow
    \lb\tb\rb\alignC\nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{$G$}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{$H$}\lb\tb\rb
\erow
% R13B12
\brow
    \cell{Vertex}
    \cell{Label}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{Vertex}
    \cell{Label}
\erow
% R14B13
\brow
    \cell{d}
    \cell{101}
    \bb\cell{}\bb
    \cell{d}
    \cell{101}
\erow
% R15B14
\brow
    \lb\rb\bb\nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\sc{(c)}\lb\rb\bb
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par % \par to align the tabular

\caption{Labels on the non-mapped vertices of $G$ and $H$ with mapping: Fig (a) $M={a,b}$, Fig. (b) $M={ab,bc}$, and (c) $M={abc, bca}$}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you load the `subcaption` package, which provides an environment called `subtable`. To (more or less) replicate the structure shown in the screenshot you posted, you could set up three `subtable` environments, each with its own `\caption`, inside the overall `table` environment. In the code below, each `subtable` contains two `tabular` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other, more suitable document class
\usepackage{array} % for '\extrarowheight' macro
\usepackage{subcaption} % for 'subtable' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt} % for a more open "look"

\centering

\begin{subtable}{.55\linewidth} % choose width suitably
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} % 1st tabular
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$G$}\\
\hline
Vertex & Label\\ 
\hline
b & 1 \\
c & 1 \\
d & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\hfill % maximize distance between adjacent tabulars
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} % 2nd tabular
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$H$}\\
\hline
Vertex & Label\\ 
\hline
c & 1 \\
a & 1 \\
d & 1 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\caption{$M=\{a,b\}$}
\end{subtable}

\vspace{5mm} % insert a bit of vertical whitespace
\begin{subtable}{.55\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$G$}\\
\hline
Vertex & Label\\ 
\hline
c & 11 \\
d & 10 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$H$}\\
\hline
Vertex & Label\\ 
\hline
a & 11 \\
d & 11 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\caption{$M=\{ab,bc\}$}
\end{subtable}

\vspace{5mm}
\begin{subtable}{.55\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$G$}\\
\hline
Vertex & Label\\ 
\hline
d & 101 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$H$}\\
\hline
Vertex & Label\\ 
\hline
d & 110 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\caption{$M=\{abc,bca\}$}
\end{subtable}

\caption{Labels on the non-mapped vertices of $G$ and $H$, for selected choices of mapping $M$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I use the subfloat package which is incompatible with the subcaption one.

Comment: @Mdp11 - I’m not familiar with a package called `subfloat`. However, I’m familiar with a package called `subfig`, which provides a macro called `\subfloat`.

Comment: yes, sorry, I meant the subfig package.